# How should I correctly integrate social media SSO with my custom login service?

Tags: android, facebook, single-sign-on, google-plus

I'm trying to integrate an existing login system for a mobile application with some social media sign-in solutions. I successfully managed to integrate both facebook and google+ sign in with my app and I get to the point where the users are signed in and I can get their social information.

But now I was left wondering which would be the best approach in order to integrate users that decided to use a social media account with my native login system. Should I use their email accounts as login and maybe generate a password on the server side? Or maybe use an oauth token instead of a password?

I need to keep track of my users, even the ones that did not formally filled a registration form. So what should I place instead of email + password?

Comment: in case of facebook you can use facebook userid as passworad and username of facebook as user.

Comment: Not really safe. Because if someone happens to decompile my app and figures out I'm doing this, it would be easy to try those two pieces of public information to hijack valid user accounts.

Comment: So if I understood it well, you have a system which allows your users to log in using a Social network login (FB, G+) and you need to store their data, but you need to decide what to use as their credentials? So you'll have a double authentication? Or you want to make them avoid login each time they connect by storing some data from their phones?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This can be tricky - the majority case is easy, but you need to think about the edges. I find it easer to consider email/password as just another authentication mechanism. You want

1. A user record with the core data about that user (perhaps name, email address, app specific profile data etc.)
2. A series of records for their connected auth methods, e.g. Google+, Facebook, user/pass.

The connected auth methods can store the relevant information for those methods - e.g. for Google it would likely be Google user Id and perhaps refresh token if using offline access. This makes it easy for you to offer connecting multiple social accounts.

Password may be a special case that you want to store against the original user record. In that case, if someone signs-up using a social login, then you can either generate a random password, or leave it null. Either way, as long as you request the email address for the user, you can always let them go through a Forgot Password flow (where you generate and email them a password) if they want to access their account but no longer have their 3p login.

What you don't want to do if avoidable is to force the users to give you a new password just after they sign in. However, it you are allowing multiple login methods to be associated with one account, you might want to allow associating them. So, your flow might be:

- User signs in (with 3p or email/pass)
- If you have a record for that login method (e.g. matching Google or Facebook user id, matching email/pass combination), sign the user in, and you are done.
- If you have no matching record for that sign in method:

  1. See if you have a matching email address with an existing user account. If you do, some sites automatically merge the new login method to this account. If privacy/security is more of a concern you might want to confirm the user wants to login to that account, or make them go through a 1-time validation (e.g. "it looks like you've signed in with a password before, please enter your password now to link your account and your Google account" etc.). Then link the accounts and continue as if signed in.
  2. See if you have an account which *may* be that person. E.g, perhaps you have an account with a matching name. In that case, you might want to hint the user to connect their accounts (e.g. a prompt somewhere that says "have you connected before with Facebook? Click here to link these accounts" which then takes the user through a sign in process for the login method you suspect they might have).
  3. If they look totally new, create a new user record, and treat them as newly signed up.

Its significantly easier if you can treat email address as a unique field. That means if someone signs in with a 3p account associated with an email address you already have a user for you might have to force them to link their account before continuing. If they didn't want to and you required an email address, you could prompt them to enter one manually and then validate it as normal by sending them an email and having them confirm it.

ChrLipp's links are good, also take a look at the guide for using FB and G+ together on the Google Developers site: https://developers.google.com/+/best-practices/facebook

Answer (score 3):

How did you implement the social media sign-in's? For example Facebook: did you use [Login for Android](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook)? In this case the docs say under [Checking login status](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow):

*Apps using our SDKs can check whether someone has already logged in using built-in functions. All other apps must create their own way of storing when a person has logged in, and when that indicator is not there, proceed on the assumption that they are logged out.*

And if you follow the link to [Storing access tokens and login status](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow#token) you can read:

*The token should be stored so it's available to all parts of the app when it makes API calls. ... If you're building a ... mobile app, then you should use the datastore available to your app. Also, the app should store the token in a database along with the `user_id` to identify it.*

Have an enumeration (NativeLogin, Facebook, GooglePlus) and depending on this enumeration the following information:

- NativeLogin
  UserName, Password
- Facebook and GooglePlus
  Facebook or GooglePlus ID and their [User Access Token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens)

In all cases you should store the email adress you get in an additional field.